# Call function inside $mdDialog from parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I need to call a **function** in **$mdDialog**. This function is being passed to my directive from the parent.

```
<get-list callback="getList()" ></get-list>
```

To get the function on my get-list directive.

```
function directive() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      callback: '&?'
    },
    templateUrl: "",
    controller: function($scope) {
      'ngInject';

}
```

now inside my get-list directive, I have a $mdDialog.

```
  $scope.save = function(){
    $mdDialog.show({
      templateUrl: '',
      escapeToClose: true,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,

      controller: function($scope) {

        $scope.teste = function(){
          $scope.callback()
        }

      }
    })
  }
```

I need to call the function getList() inside it, and I'm getting the error
**$scope.callback() is not a function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$mgDialog` has an isolated scope that is different from the one of your directive,
you can try to keep track of the original scope and use it in `$mgDialog` controller

```
 $scope.save = function(){
    var outerScope = $scope;
    $mdDialog.show({
      templateUrl: '',
      escapeToClose: true,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.teste = function(){
          outerScope.callback();
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

or pass the callback as a parameter

```
$scope.save = function(){
    $mdDialog.show({
      templateUrl: '',
      escapeToClose: true,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      locals: {
        callback: $scope.callback
      },
      controller: function($scope, callback) {
        $scope.teste = function(){
          callback();
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: what will do if method have one or two parameter?